# Using subprocess.call to crop an image

Tags: python, imagemagick

I'm having trouble in my python script, and I don't understand it :

```
subprocess.call(['convert', file, '-crop', '80x10+90+980', '+repage', 'test.jpg'])
```

Returns "*invalid argument - -crop*"

But if I run this from the command line, it works fine :

```
convert test.jpg -crop 80x10+90+980 +repage test.jpg
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there more than one `convert` in the system? Try an absolute path to the command you want?

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [python image library instead](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)? That seems much more reliable than to call a subprocess (especially for error handling...).

Comment: Well I want to use crop and compare.. does the PIL provide that ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "compare", but PIL is certainly able to crop images.

Answer (score 1):

`file` is a _____builtin_____ class. Overriding it may produce unwanted results. Try using a different variable name.

Comment: I changed it to "fichier" (french for file), but the problem remains. Thanks for the tip anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually tried your code:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['convert', 'capa.jpg', '-crop', '80x10+90+980', '+repage', 'capa2.jpg'])
0
>>>
```

And it works for me!

So you must have something wrong, somewhere else. Check our assumptions again.